# how to add border on listview?

Tags: android, listview, border

below is my code which display listview but problem is when i focus listview border will remove see this image border will show  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv7mX.jpg  when i focus  border will remove  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lsBB.jpg     why is remove when focus? i didnot get problem help me plzz

```
             <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtCopyright"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:background="@drawable/border2" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/lytTitlebar"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listMainMenu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector"
            android:dividerHeight="1dip"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true" />
    </LinearLayout>


     <!---listview_selector.xml ---->>>>


        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <item
android:state_focused="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/listviewborder" />

   <item
     android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/listview_selector_pressed" />

        </selector>




  <------- /listviewborder.xml---->


       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item> 
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="#000000" /> 
</shape>
  </item>   
<item android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp"  android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" 
    >  
 <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
 <gradient
 android:startColor="#0a89f1"
android:endColor="#56768d"
 android:angle="90" />
</shape>
  </item>    
    </layer-list> 



<------------listview_selector_pressed.xml-------->






           <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item> 
  <shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="#000000" /> 
  </shape>
  </item>   
  <item android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp"  android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" 
      >  
 <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
 <gradient
   android:startColor="#0a89f1"
  android:endColor="#56768d"
  android:angle="90" />
   </shape>
   </item>    
  </layer-list> 






               public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtText);


    holder.txtText.setText(HomeMenu.Category_name.get(position));

    return convertView;





       <----- main_menu_item.xml ---------->



          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"



android:padding="10dp">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txtText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text"

            android:textSize="20sp"


            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/imgNav"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/nav_next1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
             </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try 5 padding in LinearLayout

Comment: If the listview occupies your entire screen, then you can add borders to your layout that inturn will look as if it surrounds the listView. Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203606/android-how-to-draw-a-border-to-a-linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml file for border then use this as a drawable with listview

border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#00000000" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#808080" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

</shape>

<ListView
      android:background="@drawable/border"
 />
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/listMainMenu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/listviewborder" <!-- HERE -->
            android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector"
            android:dividerHeight="1dip"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is   android:background="@drawable/listviewborder" <!-- HERE -->

Comment: You forgot to add background to your listview, so the list view is not showing the border.