# PopupWindow showing a border

Tags: android

When creating a `PopupWindow` it shows a border like in the following image:

[image]

How do I remove it?

Comment: post your code so that it helps to give you proper answer.

Answer (score 24):

Try to add this line :

```
mPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day :D!

Comment: `BitmapDrawable()` is deprecated now. Can you sugggest any alterntive ?

Comment: @Sushant `new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), (Bitmap) null)` seems to work

Comment: Also you can use `new ColorDrawable(backgroundColor)`

Answer (score 3):

You can create one custom style and put that border the same color on background, try something like:

New | Android XML File.

**myborder.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<stroke 
android:width="1dip" 
android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" /> 
<solid 
android:color="@android:color/background_dark" /> 
<padding 
android:left="7dip" 
android:top="7dip" 
android:right="7dip" 
android:bottom="7dip" /> 
<corners 
android:radius="6dip" /> 
</shape>
```

Using the drawable Android XML file in a layout

**Layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/myborder"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="Text"
/>

<!-- ..................... -->
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to create a custom layout and set border of parent layout,**

i'll giving you a Logical idea for doing this.

Your layout must be like below.
**dialog_layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinerLayout>  <!-- You can **Set/Remove** all background properties of this LinearLayout-->

     <!-- Here are all child element like EditText/ Or TedxView-->

    </LinerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here are link for border :

[Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203606/android-how-to-draw-a-border-to-a-linearlayout)

Comment: hi iam using the listpopupwindow using list adapter.please suggest how to remove the border from popup window.

Comment: dialog.setBackgroundDrawable(null); please try this.

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal how to make background rounded for same. That is I am also using listpopupwindow using list adapter. I am getting sharp corners but i want rounded corners how can we achieve this?