# Android - Change background color of margin

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-layout

I have a fragment named `HostFragment` which nests one to four other fragments.

This is the layout of `HostFragment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hostFragmentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

The important part of this is `android:layout_marginTop="12dp"`.

**Background:** The nested fragments cover the entirety of `HostFragment` except for this margin. When the nested fragments change their background color (by calling `Canvas#drawColor`), `HostFragment` needs to also change the color of this margin to match. I store the needed color in `SharedPreferences`.

**Behavior:** If the user goes from `HostFragment` to `SettingsActivity`, changes the color, and comes back to `HostFragment`, the nested fragments will change their color immediately (through their `onResume()` methods), but `HostFragment`'s margin will still be the old color. If the user then leaves `HostFragment` and goes to another fragment, then returns to `HostFragment`, the margin will update its color. I don't know how or why - I have no code in `HostFragment` to update the color. The code in `HostFragment` only deals in swapping in and out nested fragments.

**Problem:** I need the margin color to update right away, so in `onResume()`, I've tried something like `mTableLayout.setBackgroundColor(...)` or even `mView.setBackgroundColor(...)` (`mView` is the layout I inflate in `onCreateView()`). This still doesn't work, and the color will only update if the user leaves and comes back.

**Question:** How can I change the color of the margin to match an `int` value in `SharedPreferences` once the user returns to `HostFragment` from another `Activity` (*i.e.* Right after the user returns from the Settings)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try giving `paddingTop` instead of `marginTop` and then change the color of the view in `onResume` by `mView.setBackgroundColor(...)`

Comment: @AbhishekV Add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @pez Done. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try giving `paddingTop` instead of `marginTop` and then change the color of the view in `onResume` by `mView.setBackgroundColor(...)`.

- **Margin** is the space outside the View so background color of a view won't reflect in margin space.
- **Padding** is the space inside of a view and background color given to a View will be applied to padding space as well.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/c1_cnxlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/c2_cnxlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the color of a margin is not possible. To achieve something that looks like that though, there's two things to do.

1) Use padding instead of margin.
Margin is outside of an element, while padding is inside of the element. This means that the element will grow in size, and that the color you've given your element as background-color will also apply to the area around the content.

2) Use a border, or drawable.
This way of doing it requires more work, but is very highly configurable. Creating a border is done by simply setting a drawable as background, and giving it a stroke width and color. For more information (and an example implementation) see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8203840/4330555.

For more information on margin, padding, border etc. see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp. This website explains it for CSS, but the concept is the same pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the color `.setBackgroundColor(...)` should work in `onResume()`, but you should be aware that as it has been pointed out above, a margin area is the space that is left **outside** from your view within the reference of its parent view. That is why changing a view´s background color would not have effect on the margin. What you could do is add a `FrameLayout`that wraps your `TableLayout` so that your `TableLayout` has a reference to set the margin from. In that case, you should be able to change `FrameLayout`'s background and it should affect the desired margin area.

In the image below, the red rectangle represents your `TableLayout` as you can see on the left, it is the root view of your `HostFragment`and the margin area is outside of your reach.On the right, the root view of your `HostFragment` is a `FrameLayout` and the red rectangle is still your `TableLayout`. In the later case, you can change the color of the `FrameLayout`.

image : http://oi59.tinypic.com/jz8q46.jpg

Answer (score 0):

best way is to use background resource specifying multiple shapes with different color and use margin or padding..