# Set border to LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to set a border to a LinearLayout when the user click on it. Every solution I have tried so far change the color of all the LinearLayout, not just the border.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the code I have used to add the border :

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
drawable.setStroke(1, Color.BLACK);
relativelayout_main.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a background resource item using a selector for clicked/not clicked state that uses a shape with a specific color/stroke width or something like that.

Something like what is listed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8203840/3934023 but combined with the selector to use that only in the clicked state, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5295522/3934023.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I followed the instruction,I did get the border, but the inside is black.

Comment: I tried  <solid android:color="#00000000" /> inside the shape,  but nothing changed

Comment: Black is represented in hex with 000000, so that's behaving correctly.  Please post what you have in your original post, I'll take a look.