# How can I add a border to a Space (or alternative Views)?

Tags: java, android, border

I've been wanting to add a border to an `ImageLayout` and a `Space`. I've managed to add a border to an `ImageLayout` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263611/border-for-an-image-view-in-android/) question. However, when I tried to replicate the code for a `Space`, it didn't work. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203606/android-how-to-draw-a-border-to-a-linearlayout/) answer but it also didn't add a border.

How can I add a border to a `Space`, or is there another alternative to a `Space` which I can add a border to?

ImageView code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

LinearLayout code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />
</shape>
```

Comment: I would use normal `View` instead of `Space`, and then use shape drawable as its background.

Comment: @Jay Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin instead of padding. Margin will create a distance between two layer where padding only move the content from layer.

```
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
<margin android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
```